# Can I take loan for my mother's Hajj

Tags: hajj, loan

My calculations suggest that I might be able to afford for my Hajj next year Insha'Allah. My mother has not performed Hajj yet therefore I do not want to go to Hajj without her. However, she cannot afford for her Hajj herself and I might not be able to afford two Hajj expenses by next year.

Can I take loan for my mothers Hajj in this situation? If yes, is this considered bad?

Comment: For clarification, are you talking about an *interest-bearing* loan in particular, or any loan?

Comment: @goldPseudo: No interest. I know people who will be very glad to give me loan on this purpose, without any interest.

Comment: you could also rotate the question to ask if "*Can a poor person who has debt allowed to preform Hajj?*" that is for you after you take a loan to give it to your mom, then, *"Can a person perform Hajj if his immediate family member has a loan in my case it is my son*", that is for your mom after you take the loan. Or, as usual, put forth your financial condition, "*can I, along with my mother perform Hajj? or should I let only her go, if I have enough only for one person?*" or something like that....

Answer (score 1):

Since she can not afford, then she is not required to perform Haj.

As for the loan, if you mean a loan that can generate any interest then it is Haram and she must not do it.

If someone like a relative or a friend will lend her the money and she is sure that she can pay the lender back his or her money, then she can do that but there are some conflicts as some say that we should stick to the rule that only the capable should do it.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you take our [tour], check our [help] and visit our [meta] to learn more about our site.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no interest or any types of fees or extra payments etc involved then it will be Qard Hasan which is permitted.

Basically you will pay back exactly the same amount that you borrowed.

If there is interest involved then this is not allowed.

If there's any other types of payments involved such as "admin fee" or "late payment fee" etc then you need to wait for someone more qualified to answer.

Allah knows best.

Comment: It would be good if you present some references. Thanks.

Comment: Off topic question but how exactly do you pay back the same amount you borrowed without interest? If I borrow $1000 today from you, and pay you back $1000 in 5 years, clearly I am not paying back what I borrowed (consider inflation as an example)

Comment: @masfenix Not an off topic question at all, this is total valid question as islamic point of view, kindly increase your knowledge

Comment: @user921, he is not most likely taking a loan in other currency where your question holds some validity, but within same currency system, there isn't a problem